# For Loop filtering data frame for rows that meet criteria from separate data frame containing null values

Tags: r, for-loop, na

I have two data frames and a for loop. The first data frame's rows represent separate customers with their financial information represented in each column. The second data frame includes a new set of bounds that will help me filter my first data frame.

The for loop is meant to go through the first data frame, find any rows where at least one value is outside the bounds imposed by the second data frame and filter out these rows into a new data frame.

I keep getting an error stating "Error in Region[, r] : incorrect number of dimensions." I'm assuming this is because the second data frame with the new bound limits include NA values so I guess the issue is my current for loop does not have a rule to ignore these but I'm not sure what that would look like.

Here is the first data frame:

```
ApplicationID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
Profit <- c(100000,50000,-100000,200000,
            200, 100, 2000000, 10000000)
Expenses <- c(50000, 10000, 5000000, 500,
              100, 100, 500, 100000)
CreditScore <- c(10, 9, 4, 6,
                 1, 2, 3, 5)

Customer_Info <- data.frame(cbind(ApplicationID, Profit, 
Expenses,CreditScore))
```

Second data frame:

```
max <-c(100000, 10000, NA)
min <-c(10000, NA, 5)

Limits <- data.frame(cbind(max, min))

rownames(Limits) <- c("Profit", "Expenses", "CreditScore")
```

My loop so far:

```
New_table<- data.frame()
for(r in rownames(Limits)){
  if(!is.na(Limits[r,"max"])){
    max_rows <- Customer_Info %>% subset(Customer_Info[,r]
                                         >Limits[r,"max"])
    New_table<-rbind(New_table, max_rows)}
  if(!is.na(Limits[r,"min"])){
    min_rows <- Customer_Info %>% subset(Customer_Info[,r]
                                         <Limits[r,"min"])
    New_table<-rbind(New_table, min_rows)}
}
```

If there is a function out there that can do this, even better. The output would be an updated version of the first data frame with out the rows included where any of their values fall outside the new limits from data frame two.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when your `for` loop hits the "Credit" row of `Limits` and tries to select the `Credit` column `Customer_Info` (which does not exist). This can be easily solved in one of two ways:

Change:

```r
rownames(Limits) <- c("Profit", "Expenses", "Credit")
```

To:

```r
rownames(Limits) <- c("Profit", "Expenses", "CreditScore")
```

**or** change:

```r
CreditScore <- c(10, 9, 4, 6,
                 1, 2, 3, 5)
```

To:

```r
Credit <- c(10, 9, 4, 6, 
            1, 2, 3, 5)
```

Comment: Apologies about the misspelling, that was user issue. I'm working with private data that I can't share so the data you see is a substitution of the data I'm actually working with. The for loop is currently what I have and it's still giving me the error mentioned above.

Comment: It works fine for me. Have you tried running (all of) your example code with the revision?

Comment: Yup, turns out that wasn't the part of the code that was the issue. I think having to type up the code here and explain it actually helped me figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Cool - glad you figured it out. An upvote/confirmation of my answer would be appreciated!